# SubArray, passing address to a function

Tags: c, memory-address

I have a question regarding passing address of first element of an array to a (recursive) function:

```
selectionSort( &b[1], size-1);
```

When address is passed to a function, function parameter must be a pointer as I know. `selectionSort` method gets `int b[]` as argument. Not a pointer.

But code works without any problems. Also this code generates subarrays. When we pass the 1st element does it become the subarray's zeroeth element?

```
void selectionSort(int b[], int size)
{
    int temp,i;

    if (size>=1) 
    {
        for (i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            if (b[i]<b[0])
            {
                temp=b[0];
                b[0]=b[i];
                b[i]=temp;
            }
        }
        selectionSort( &b[1], size-1 );  
    }
}
```

Comment: "it became as subarrays zeroeth element?" - ***What?***

Comment: Also, [arrays are not pointers](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html), but they can [decay into one.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying).

Comment: Sorry for my English. I tried to say that, when original array's first elements address, is sent to function, this element becomes subarray's 0'th element? This is crazy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you have a function like:

```
void f(int b[]);
```

this is the same as

```
void f(int *b);
```

The `[]` syntax for function parameters is just a special syntax to let the reader know that you intend to use the parameter like an array, but it is actually just a pointer.  You can't pass an actual array to a function.  Pointers and arrays work very similarly in C, so for the most part you can work with a pointer as if it were an array (but be careful -- there are important exceptions).

For example, when you access an element of an array like this:

```
array[index]
```

this is the same as

```
*(array+index)
```

and it doesn't matter whether `array` is a real array or just a pointer.

So `&b[1]` is the same as `&*(b+1)`, which is the same as `b+1`.

If we were to write the code so that we see the `b` parameter as a pointer, it would look like this:

```
void selectionSort(int *b, int size){
    .
    .
    .

    selectionSort( b+1, size-1 );

    .
    .
    .
}
```

Now, you can see that `selectionSort` is being passed a pointer to an int, and it calls itself with a pointer to the next int.

Comment: @Gorfi `foo(int arr[])` is equivalent to `foo(int* arr)`. As pointed out, arrays passed to functions as arguments decay to pointers.

Comment: You sure he will not endup losing the array after the first run ?

Comment: @Jerry: `size--` would work, but it is doing more than necessary.  You don't need to modify `size`.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, the code will create 'sub arrays' you should use:**

**A pointer to an array of integers**

```
 selectionSort(int (*b)[], int size)
```

**And call the function using:**

```
selectionSort( &b[1], size-1 );
```

Comment: If b is a type of int * or int[], then &b[1] is a type of int *, not int ** (int *[]), isn't it?

Comment: `(int* b[])` will break the logic (he's passing an array of integers, not an array of integer pointers), it works fine as it is at present.

Comment: int* b[]; = An array of int pointers.
int (*b)[]; = A pointer to an array of integers

Comment: @Gorfi Nope, not fixed, if you insist on a pointer it can be modified to `selectionSort(int* b, int size)`

Comment: You sure he will not louse the array after the first run ? because its a recursive function, and will keep sending the array to itself